# iPhone sdk updating text field and label

Tags: iphone

I have text field and button in one class and label in another class.

I want to update label according to values in text field when button is pressed. but label is not updating automatically. i have to restart my application for that.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: post some code on how you load the two classes

Answer (score 1):

Use [delegate](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) method for this. Send back the NSString value (textfield value) to the first view controller through delegate method when the button is pressed.

In the delegate implementation method, set the value to the UILabel in the main thread, like

```
[label performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:strValue waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Also you can [refer here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

When the button is pressed, copy the text field to the label.